# What type of visa is required for a PhD interview visit to Switzerland?

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

I am applying to join a research group in a school in Switzerland and after the first round of interviews, I have been invited by the university in Zurich for an in-person interview so that I can meet the research group and give a presentation on the work I am currently doing. I intend to be in Switzerland for just a night and I am wondering what kind of visa I should be applying for? Should it be a business or tourist visa?

Comment: [A related question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/can-you-search-for-a-job-when-using-a-tourist-visa-b-2-in-the-us/13519#13519); however, it didn't get a definitive answer.

Comment: Universities often have an "international office" staffed with experts on visa and immigration issues.  You could ask to be put in touch with this office.

Comment: In the same situation (Zurich, PhD interview) in 2013 I went with a C type Schengen visa with a remark "Business".

Answer (score 6):

There are no "Business Visa" in Switzerland. There are only short-term (Type C) and long-term visa: in your case, you'll need a short term visa, the details can be read at the [FAQ](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/bfm/en/home/themen/einreise/faq.faq_3.html#a_faq_3) of the department of foreign affairs.

You will need to fill out a [Schengen visa application](http://www.bfm.admin.ch/content/dam/data/migration/einreise/visumantragsformulare/visumantrag-schen-en-de.pdf) and check "Study" in the "Main purpose" Box.

Comment: I don't think he should check "Study", since he's not actually studying. "Business" is more appropriate I believe.