# Is it permitted to look for a job while visiting the US under the Visa Waiver Program?

Tags: usa, legal, work, us-visa-waiver-program

- We already have [a question on whether you can attend a job interview or look for work while in the US on a tourist visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/can-you-search-for-a-job-when-using-a-tourist-visa-b-2-in-the-us). (Actually it's unresolved with two possibly conflicting answers and no solid reference).
- And we have [a more recent question asking about looking for work while on a business visitor visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20604/is-it-legal-to-look-for-work-in-the-us-while-on-a-b1-b2-business-visitor-visa). (Currently on hold as a duplicate of the former but maybe it's different).

But what about for people who don't require a visa to enter the US but can visit on the **Visa Waiver Program**? Are such people allowed to job hunt in America?

Comment: Given some of the answers, it might help to define more precisely what activities you mean when you say "look for a job".

Comment: The normal precise meanings. Use any dictionary to look up "look for" and "job". If it's complicated it's complicated. It is what it is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.

From [a visa website](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/au/au-niv-typee3.asp) (since the original Embassy link is dead, but same content):

Question:

> Can I travel to the United States on the Visa Waiver Program to find a
> job or attend interviews and then apply for the E-3 visa once I return
> to Australia?

Answer:

> Yes, you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the
> requirements (please see our page on the Visa Waiver Program). If you
> do not meet the VWP requirements, you may be eligible to travel on the
> B-1/B-2 Combined Visa for Business or Pleasure.
>
> You must leave the United States before applying for your E-3 visa.

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't for me so hopefully it's the same for citizens of all countries under the VWP and not just Australians.

Comment: @hippietrail indeed, and the embassy site says just "VWP" - not Australians in particular. I just chose their site as it's in the country I'm in.

Comment: Mark see if you think the other two questions should be separate for separate types of visas? They're marked as dupes for now but the accepted answer (mine) is strongly disputed.

Comment: @MarkMayo: though it does say "apply for the E-3 visa", which is only for Australians.

Comment: The link is now dead

Comment: @MatthewLock link fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Not to nitpick but ustraveldocs.com is a commercial site, not a US government site, is that right?

Comment: @MatthewLock well spotted. Hmm. I've updated.

Comment: @MatthewLock: It is kind-of official, as it is the site that all US embassies direct people to use to make nonimmigrant visa applications.

Comment: this is just so wrong @MarkMayo  At the minimum perhaps you should consider changing your "yes" at the front to something like "here is some information which I believe suggests Yes".  not to have to explain something so obvious yet again, but the "question" someone asked in passing asks *two utterly unrelated things*.  You are apparently assuming that the "Yes," in the "answer" applies definitively and explicitly to one of those questions (*Even though!* the entire rest of the very same sentence after the comma explicitly explains that is not at all the case!!)

Comment: ustraveldocs.com is run by CGI Federal, which is the commercial company that the US Government outsources visa processing to in many countries around the world.  For all due purpose, this is an official government website, albeit one physically run by a non-government company.

Comment: hi @Doc - uh, yes and that's why it says **"you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements (please see our page on the Visa Waiver Program)"**   So presumably you now agree wholeheartedly that "you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements ".  And that would be because you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements. So fortunately, anyone googling to this page now knows that you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements.

Comment: One thing ... now that you wholeheartedly agree that you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements, please note that by removing the bold emphasizing that the "question" **is two completely unrelated questions**, you are likely doing a real disservice to anyone visiting this misinformation page.

Answer (score 7):

So there are really two questions here:

1. What do *laws and regulations* say about VWP visitors looking for work during their stay in the US?
2. *Practically speaking*, if I want to visit the US to look for work, should I apply for a B-1/B-2 visa instead of trying to use VWP?

To the first question, the answer is that the allowed activities on VWP are exactly the same as the allowed activities on a B-1/B-2 visa. However, one may not apply for an extension of stay, change of status, or adjustment of status while on VWP. (There are some exceptions to this rule.)

If you don't believe me on this, here are the legal sources.

The Immigration and Nationality Act (INA) §217(a) lists the requirements that are imposed on the visitor themselves. There are various requirements that don't apply to B-1/B-2 visitors (*e.g.* must be in possession of a round-trip ticket, must not have visited Iraq or Syria, and so on). However, the sole requirement on the allowed activities while in the US is:

> (1) The alien is applying for admission during the program as a nonimmigrant visitor (described in section 1101(a)(15)(B) of this title) for a period not exceeding 90 days.

The *Foreign Affairs Manual*, while not binding, reflects the State Department's official position regarding the appropriate uses of various visas. Regarding VWP, it mentions [here](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM020101.html#M201_1_4_C):

> An alien who is a national of a participating VWP country does not require a visa, provided the alien:
>
> (1) Is applying for admission as a nonimmigrant visitor, as described in INA 101(a)(15)(B);
> (2) Seeks to enter the United States for a period not to exceed 90 days;
> ...

and:

> Nature of VWP Travel:
>
> (1) Maintenance of Status:  An alien admitted to the United States under the VWP:
>
> (a) Is admitted as a visitor for business or pleasure for a period not to exceed 90 days;
> (b) May not engage in activities inconsistent with status as a visitor;
> (c) Is not eligible for an extension of stay in the United States;
> (d) Is not eligible for adjustment of status to that of a lawful permanent resident alien (other than as an immediate relative as defined under INA 201(b) or under the provisions of INA 245(i); and
> (e) Is not eligible for change of nonimmigrant status.

The [CBP Inspector's Field Manual](https://www.shusterman.com/pdf/cbpinspectorsfieldmanual.pdf) may be more directly relevant to this situation since most ESTA applications are not manually reviewed by someone at the State Department but the determination of admissibility will be made at the port of entry. Regarding VWP, it says:

> The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) permits nationals from designated countries (listed in 8 CFR 217.2(a)) to apply for admission to the United States for ninety (90) days or less as nonimmigrant visitors for business or pleasure without first obtaining a U.S. nonimmigrant visa (USNIV).

"Business or pleasure" is the same as a B-1/B-2 visa.

It also mentions:

> An applicant for admission shall not be admitted under the VWP unless the alien convinces the examining immigration officer that he or she is clearly and beyond doubt entitled to be admitted and is not inadmissible under section 212 of the Act. The conditions for admission are specified in section 217 of the Act and 8 CFR 217.  All VWP admissions are for 90 days unless the applicant’s passport is valid for a lesser period, in which case the period of admission would be until the expiration date of the passport for those countries on the 6-month list.  In the cases of those countries not on the 6-month list, the applicants would not meet the documentary requirements in Chapter 15.7(b), Documentary Requirements, and would be inadmissible under the VWP.

This doesn't add anything beyond the statute and regulations which already specify that VWP applicants may engage in the same activities as B-1/B-2 applicants. The "clearly and beyond doubt" standard applies to all nonimmigrant applicants for admission.

In short, if you believe that B-1/B-2 visa holders are allowed to enter the US to *look for work*, you should believe the same about ESTA holders.

And by the way, USCIS also recently weighed in on the question of whether B-1/B-2 nonimmigrants can look for a job. USCIS policy is technically not binding on State (which issues visas) and CBP (which processes travellers for admission), but whenever you apply for any immigration benefit from USCIS (such as a change of status *to* B-1/B-2, where you must establish that you seek to remain in the United States for activities that are permissible in B-1/B-2 status, or an adjustment of status, where USCIS will scrutinize whether you have ever violated US immigration law), their policies apply. And the **USCIS policy states that "searching for work and interviewing for a position are permissible B-1 or B-2 activities".** [[Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20230314173123/https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/information-for-employers-and-employees/options-for-nonimmigrant-workers-following-termination-of-employment)]

Regarding the second question, my opinion is that you should just try to enter under VWP. It's very unlikely that they will tell you "no, you have to apply for a B-1 visa for that" since they are supposed to know that the allowed activities are the same. If they do refuse you admission under the VWP, you are unlikely to be approved by ESTA in the future. However, that would also be the case if you were refused admission under a B-1 visa. So, to preemptively apply for a B-1/B-2 visa now would be pointless in my opinion. If you are reading this during the COVID-19 pandemic, trying to apply for a visa would needlessly inconvenience you because many consulates are not operating at full capacity anyway.

Answer (score -8):

The answer is absolutely No as can be easily verified in zillions of sources.

(The *unusually worded* ambiguous information mentioned in the other answer, was once on a US embassy web site, but was removed as it was so confusing.)

#### EXPLANATION OF THE FAMOUS INCORRECT TEXT WHICH WAS, OF COURSE, REMOVED BY THE EMBASSY:

It's fairly annoying to have to explain this explicitly but:

The question was:

> Can I travel to the United States on the Visa Waiver Program **to find a job or attend interviews** and then apply for the E-3 visa once I return to Australia?

#### THE QUESTION IS MEANINGLESS.

- find a job
- attend interviews

could not be more different.

The question might as well ask,

**"Can I travel to visit my grandmother or buy leopards"**

**"Can I travel to see the Grand Canyon or work for Microsoft".**

and so on.

The question is **meaningless**.

#### THE ANSWER SIMPLY STATES THAT A VWP IS POSSIBLE IF YOU MEET THE REQUIREMENTS.

The answer was:

> Yes, you can travel on the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) if you meet the requirements (please see our page on the Visa Waiver Program)...

Note that the QA page ***was about*** the VWP specifically.

Since the question was meaningless - ***it asks two utterly different questions*** - the minimum-wage staffer from the embassy who wrote the answer just typed "you can use a VWP if you meet the requirements. See the actual facts on the VWP to see if you meet the requirements."

{And if you go there it, obviously, says "you cannot come to the US to look for a job". As on every other piece of information ever emitted by the US Government regarding visas!}

Equally obviously, this confusing answer was, of course, removed from the embassy web site.

As I say, it is fairly annoying to have to take time explain this explicitly because it is so glaringly obvious, and it is such an well-known fact that, of course, you cannot come to the US and look for a job.

Surely, surely, surely, surely folks as sophisticated internet users, as site visitors here, realize it's a well known problem in the information age where you get one glaringly, obviously, wrong bit of text on the net (whether about programming, physics, or whatever) gets magnified by folks endlessly repeating it over years.

Comment: This answer is wrong in every possible way. To point out the easiest error, the link in the accepted answer is still valid, and still contains the relevant text so it wasn't "removed as it was so confusing".

Comment: @Doc but the text does appear to have been removed from the embassy website; the link now points to a different website.  However, there seems to be no basis for the conclusion about the reason for its removal.

Comment: @phoog fair point, we don't *know* why it was removed but (A) it was, evidently, completely confusing - the "answer" simply restates ***"if you meet the requirements"*** and the question is a non-question .. it asks about "find a job or attend interviews" which is meaningless, those two are completely different.  (B) an utterly overwhelming number of entirely US Government sources say in plain language that (of course!) you cannot come to the US to look for a job.

Comment: @Fattie but that's simply not true.  There is no category other than WB (under the VWP) or B-1, that is appropriate for a job seeker.  All of the employment visa categories require you to have a job already.  If there truly is "an utterly overwhelming number of entirely US Government sources say in plain language that...you cannot come to the US to look for a job" then this answer ought to link to some of them.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the phrase "look for a job" is perhaps ambiguous, and I for one would indeed understand it as synonymous with "attend interviews" in some contexts.  So perhaps you could make it clear exactly what activities you understand to be included in "look for a job", and explain (with citations) which ones are forbidden or not.  In particular, to me, "look for a job" does *not* include actually starting work at a job should one be offered.

Comment: Also, if you are saying that it *is* permitted to attend interviews under the VWP, then I think that (with citations, supporting evidence, etc) would be a useful answer to what I understand the question to be asking.

Comment: hi @NateEldredge - this QA is so unbelievably silly, so ridiculous, so absurd, that I can't be bothered any more.  I don't mean to sound like a smart ass but we have brought more people to the US to work (we source experts for large companies) than there are *contributors on this page*.  we have three (3) different immigration solicitors in the US.  i myself have had I think 4 different types of visa in the US.  Sitemate MarkMayo is very unfortunately suffering a case of "I Will Never Edit My Answer Ever Ever Ever" even though it is ..

Comment: .. trivially obvious to explain the epic mistake in a few words .. "You are apparently assuming that the "Yes," in the "answer" applies definitively and explicitly to one of the two completely unrelated questions (Even though! the entire rest of the very same sentence after the comma explicitly explains that is not at all the case!!)"

Comment: The Yes answer applies equally to BOTH questions.  If I asked you if you can walk and if you can talk, the answer "yes" is correct, even if those two things are largely unrelated.  I know many people that have entered the US either to look for work or to attend interviews - including myself!  It's allowed. (And there are no such thing as "immigration solicitors in the US", which you should know given you deal with them so frequently)

Comment: yes, so that's an excellent analogy about how an answer can be yes twice, but it's wrong @Doc . (I've no idea what you mean about law firms in the US .. google "immigration attorneys" if you need one.) (A "solicitor" is a brit term.)

Comment: “Looking for a job” is to be taken literal. It consists of studying adverts, enquiring with companies, applying for jobs, taking interviews, up to accepting a job. All things I could do from abroad, but are easier in the USA themselves. It does _absolutely not_ include working. You need a visa that allows you to work in the USA for that.

Comment: @gnasher729 you can even accept a job offer as a business visitor, as long as you don't actually start work without first changing status (which isn't allowed if you've entered using the VWP).