# US E3 visa holder: can I still travel to the US on the visa waiver program?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens

I'm an Australian citizen, and I hold an E3 visa to work in the US. Can I still travel to the US for a holiday on the visa waiver program?

Comment: Huh? Why do you want to travel with an ESTA when you have an E-3 visa already...? I don't understand this...

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but the problem isn't the why. I'd like to know if it's possible.

Comment: I wonder how you will answer the ESTA question "Are you seeking to work in the US?"

Comment: As @NateEldredge pointed out more clearly and I vaguely hinted at, the answer is very likely no but we can't give you an answer until we know more. Say, if your E-3 is valid from a future date and you want to [attend a job interview](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22560/travelling-to-the-us-on-the-visa-waiver-program-vwp-to-attend-a-job-interview) on an ESTA that is doable. But if the E-3 is in effect why on earth do you need an ESTA?

Comment: @chx perhaps he wants to go be a tourist. Can you do that with an E-3 visa?

Comment: I want to go as a tourist, that's all. The E3 is valid now, but I don't want to travel on it for a quick holiday.

Comment: This makes *no sense*! To have an E-3 you must have a job in the USA so you are a resident there, how can you go for a quick holiday to your place of residency?? If you don't have a job there then how earth do you have an E-3?

Comment: @chx you have to get the E-3 *before you move to the US.*  Presumably you can also *leave the US before the visa expires.*  It certainly seems like an unusual situation, but it is by no means a nonsensical one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. If you want to go to the US, and the trip isn't for an E-3 purpose, but does qualify you as a visitor for business or pleasure, you can enter on the VWP or a B-1/B-2 visa.

I'm not sure what would disqualify you from traveling as an E-3 but not as a B or VWP visitor, but I imagine there might be reasons such relating to your US employment, or perhaps simply wanting to visit for pleasure.

It may also be possible to travel for pleasure on your E-3, though, which would save you 14 bucks. I don't know whether that is the case.