# Is it allowed to look for a job (not work) while I'm in the US under Visa Waiver Program

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program, working-visas, tourism, interview

**Disclaimer:**

1. I know there are similar questions here already but the answers are a bit conflicting and I didn't find quite the same question I have. Most were also quite old.
2. I know that during current COVID-19 times getting work visa is pretty much impossible for foreigners but let's please focus on the case when the country opens up more.

---

**Question:**

I have been thinking about working in the US (among couple of other options) in the near future (when COVID permits hehe) but would like to also make a round trip for couple of months to see the country before. If I do decide for the US as my next work destination then can I continue using my free time during tourism as a time to also research job offers?

So, is it allowed to look for job (*NOT WORK*) while visiting the US under the Visa Waiver Program? What I mean is that a person has a ticket to fly back home bought and is planning to switch to work visa before starting.

I'd imagine no-one can prohibit the person to explore the positions while searching the internet as it isn't different from researching positions online from anywhere else? How about interviews? Online? In person?

**Additional question:**
If the case above is allowed then is it possible to switch from using Visa Waiver Program to work visa while being abroad? Not really seeing this case happening even if possible but would give a better picture of possibilities.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Can you explain why your question is not the same as https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20614/is-it-permitted-to-look-for-a-job-while-visiting-the-us-under-the-visa-waiver-pr?rq=1 ?

Comment: The main question is answered at the link.  As for the additional question, the answer is that you have no US immigration status to switch from when you are outside the US.  In other words, you are not using the VWP when you are abroad, so there is no need to speak of "switching."  You would simply present your work visa the next time you enter the US.  You cannot switch from the VWP to another status while you're in the US, but you can switch from B visa status to another status.  It costs a few hundred dollars.